# Like a necromancer, but not evil

Tags: word-request

I'm trying to figure out if there is a name for a person (male or female) who is a necromancer, but isn't evil. Maybe some old religious or ancient name.

The person is a made-up character to a book. She is a fallen druid, but fallen in a way of having a different way of seeing death. She loves dead animals and skeletons, and talks to them, gives them a second life, she supports the idea that death is not the end, unlike the druid she once was.

Is there a name for such a necromancer?

Comment: "gives them a second life":  she literally resurrects them?

Comment: Yes,, resurrects them

Comment: But what determines if she is good or evil? All necromancers are evil from a Catholic point of view, for example. She may be evil from the point of view of the traditional druids. I think that probably there is not an specific word for a good or white necromancer. If you do magic with the dead, you are a necromancer by definition.

Comment: @RubioRic That's a good point, I'm indeed looking for the term "white necromancer"... She herself isn't dead, she is pretty and good, she loves the dead as much as she loves the living.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because naming things is listed as explicitly off-topic in the help center. Yes, these are fun questions but they are by their nature opinion based.

Comment: Nothing in the Merriam-Webster definition of [necromancer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/necromancer) says anything about good or evil. In *Dungeons and Dragons* (for example), I'm quite sure you can play a Lawful Good necromancer. (There is no more a single word for "good necromancer" than there is for "bad necromancer".)

Comment: @Jason Bassford: That's just one definition, Jason. It's not gospel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking cues from your character and setting, specifically:

> Maybe some old religious or ancient name...
>   She is a fallen druid...
>   She loves dead animals...
>   She supports the idea that death is not the end...

There is a Celtic God Named: [Cernunnos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cernunnos)

> Cernunnos was a Celtic god of fertility, life, animals, wealth, and the underworld.

Celtic (Druid), Life, Animals, and the Underworld (death)! Hits all four!

You can play with the name, make it feminine: **Cernunna**, **Cernunnia**

Or create a special type of necromancer: **Curnunnian Necromancer**

---

Of course that means writing a bit of background about the God, Curnunnos, to your story so that your readers will understand the meaning behind your term for her, which could be fantastic.
But if you want a term that your readers can understand right away, then I suggest building a new word from two familiar titles or classes of fantasy characters:

Necromancer + Druid  = **Necrodruid**
Necromancer + Shaman (spiritualist / animalist) = **Necroshaman**
Necromancer + Cleric (healer) = **Necrocleric**
Necromancer + Paladin (holy knight) = **Necropaladin**

By the Way, having a dark assumption of the word necromancer could be used to your advantage depending on the story. For instance, if the other Druids call her by this "dark" title "Necro-something", then perhaps she is simply misunderstood and the story reveals her true goodness which shapes the readers' and the other characters' understanding of the title from dark towards light over time.

Comment: I like the idea, I am afraid that without necromancer, the idea of her character will be weak, people will associate

Answer (score 2):

We can make one up:

Resurrectrix

Albatrix

Comment: Why not `resurrector` (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/resurrector)

Comment: @lebatsnok: **--trix** is the suffix for Latinate nouns that refer to a woman who who has a particular role or who performs a particular task or job.  **-or** is the masculine ending.  It is analogous to **-ess** in "sorceress" and "enchantress" given in casey's answer.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo is there necromantrix?

Comment: @SovereignSun: Perhaps there is  *necromanseuse*. But *necro* implies "dark arts" or "black magic"

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo yup ... but I'd think indicating the gender of a mythological being is not  really a priority, and the OP asked fore version of _necromancer_, not _necromanceuse_ or something alike. In that sense, `resurrector` makes more sense as an answer, as it has, etymologically, a male ending, just as `necromancer`. Many Latinate words in -or and -er are equally used for men and women: _doctor_ (not _doctoress_), _conductor_ (I wonder if anyone says _conductress_ but apparently such a word exists), _professor_ (not, I hope, _professeuse_ :).

Comment: Whether -trix would be perceived as unequivocally feminine is another matter. There is the Latin -trix which is feminine but speaking about Druids, Vercingetorix (not to mention Astérix and Obélix) were all men. And Bellatrix (saw the movie with my son the other day:)) was so very bad ... so perhaps Resurretrix would sound bad as well.

Comment: @lebatsnok: The gender of mythological creatures is quite often a very relevant fact.   -torix is not -trix, and if people understand how the -trix ending works, they won't confuse them. But if they do, that's not really my concern.

Answer (score 0):

[Wizard](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wizard)

[Magician](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/magician)

[Enchantress](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enchantress)

[Sorceress](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sorceress)

Answer (score 0):

I found a term "hallowed necromancer" which is said to be something more holy than just a white necromancer and I think it suits best my needs, unless someone proves me wrong.

I wonder if I can use "necromantrix" referring to a female necromancer?

Comment: Hallowed Necromancer is oxymoronic.

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: Because *necro* refers to "black" magic, and the hallowed or the holy is associated with "white" magic.

Comment: Actually, it refers to death, although since the two sound similar they were confused historically.